# SolrCoreInitalizationException: SolrCore 'solrprodshard2' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

We store our Index in shared NAS drive. To perform DR exercise, we switched NAS to different cluster and reverted back. During this time we removed write.lock files on Index. When we reconfigured the NAS to original cluster, we are not able to bring it back to original state.

We are seeing above error for all the cores. Is there a way to preserve index and connect them back to original nodes?

```
in solr cloud mode, we are not able to see Disk usage data in dashboard.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The stacktrace should have the underlying exception - i.e. _why_ it can't open the new searcher. That's usually the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @MatsLindh it says that Solr core 'solrprodshard2' is not available due to init failure.(No 'segments' file found in LockValidatigDirectoryWrapper

Comment: Seems like it's unable to find its segments file - i.e. the index isn't being loaded from where you assume it's being loaded? Is the index in the index location properly structured?

Comment: yea it should be coz it is in default space where the data directory is present. Should  I specifically give a try with the path name in solr.in.sh ?

Comment: @MatsLindh seems like there is no segments* file in the indexes of all shards except one shard (which did not throw any error) Is there a way to recreate it ?

Comment: The segment files are the index itself, so without knowing anything more about your situation I wouldn't think so; the data each index on a node is made up of one or more segments, if you don't have the segments, you don't really have anything.

Comment: @MatsLindh is there a way to reload index using tlog?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the low level structure of the tlog - I'm guessing it would depend on how long your tlog is and what index you have as a starting point. Try posting to the solr-user mailing list with detailed information about your exact case.